# Some users not showing up in search parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a parse app for iOS where it is sometimes necessary to search all the users. For some reason though, the users exist in the database but other users cannot see them in a search. I have seen no correlation between users or reason for this the only thing I'm thinking is maybe parse is not searching ALL users? Here is the code for the search

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"_User";
        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"isTeacher" equalTo:@"True"];
    [query whereKey:@"schoolName" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"schoolName"]];




    return query;
}
```

I'm assuming if there was a problem it would be in the above, but the rest of the code is here if need be:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
    }
    // Configure the cell
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {


        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }


    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        PFObject* object = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];

        //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        }
    }






    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *teacherUsername = cell.textLabel.text
    ;

    //NSLog(teacherUsername);


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:teacherUsername forKey:@"teacherUsername"];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];



}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {

        return self.objects.count;

    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;

    }

}

-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"isTeacher" equalTo:@"True"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        NSArray *results = [NSArray arrayWithArray:objects];

        NSLog(@"%@", results);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)results.count);
        NSLog(@"results^");


        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];

        NSPredicate *searchPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchTerm];
        _searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"%@", _searchResults);
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_searchResults.count);
        NSLog(@"search results^");


    }];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Is there any reason why certain users would not show up? I have checked the obvious things, making sure the users have the same "schoolName" and "isTeacher" is true but I'm stumped. Attached is a screenshot of an example user in the parse core[image]

Comment: How many users are you getting back from the query?

Comment: I have 1.3k users, but for this query I should only be getting about 170 (only 170 teachers) @LyndseyScott

Comment: I asked you how many you *are* getting, but that's OK... I think I know what's going on. (You're probably getting 100.) I'll write up an answer.

Comment: And yes I am getting 100!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit for a `Parse` query is 100 objects so even though you expect 170 `PFObjects`, you need to specify that you want to receive 170+ objects from your query in order to receive them all from the query using the [`limit`](http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/limit) parameter, ex:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"isTeacher" equalTo:@"True"];
[query setLimit: 1000]; // <-- increase the limit up to 1000
```

The upper limit for the number of `PFObject`s a `PFQuery` can return though is 1000, so since you have more than 1000 users and could hypothetically need to receive more than 1000 results when performing a different query, you can do so by looping through multiple queries while utilizing an increasing [`skip`](http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/skip) parameter, to specify the "number of objects to skip before returning any."

So whereas that first block of code I wrote will return the first 1000 objects from that query, the next 1000 can be retrieved like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query whereKey:@"isTeacher" equalTo:@"True"];
[query setLimit: 1000]; // <-- increase the limit up to 1000
[query setSkip: 1000]; // <-- skip the first 1000 already found
```

And generally speaking, although it's probably best to receive your results bit by bit and increment setSkip to receive more results only when you absolutely need them, you can hypothetically retrieve all the objects matching your query at once, like so:

```
- (void)theOriginalCallingMethod {
    // Start out by fetching the maximum number of results
    // from the query and start at the beginning, i.e.
    // not skipping anything
    [self performTeacherQueryWithLimit:1000 andSkip:0];
}

- (void)performTeacherQueryWithLimit:(int)limit andSkip:(int)skip {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"isTeacher" equalTo:@"True"];
    [query setLimit: limit];
    [query setSkip: skip];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        // If the maximum number of objects is found, there
        // may be more, so continue querying
        if (objects.count == limit) {
            // Perform the query using the same limit, but increase
            // the skip amount by that current limit to indicate
            // that the next query should skip the results we just
            // found
            [self performTeacherQueryWithLimit:limit andSkip:skip+limit];
        }

        // ...other code...

    }];
}
```

**Note:** This will only work with a `PFTableView` as long as its `paginationEnabled` property is set to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am a little confused about the setSkip though. I have 3,000 users in another one so obviously I will need to use it however I assume it is not just as easy as adding [setSkip: 1000] I am trying to understand the documentation but could you elaborate on how this works?

Comment: @user2547771 `[query setSkip: 1000]` skips the first 1000 queries... And you also have to set pagination to NO which I can see you've already done in your init. It should be as simple as that. It should be within the PFQuery doc. I'll try to find a link...

Comment: @user2547771 "skip" from the docs: http://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/skip

Comment: Do you mind if I ask another question about how this applies directly to my code? I am a bit confused about the different methods, or would you prefer I edit my question

Comment: @user2547771 So far in your current code if you want less than 1000 results, all you need to do is add `[query setLimit: 1000];`. Once you want more than 1000 results from your query, then it will get more complicated... You'll have to use a `setSkip` parameter. Chances are though, you won't have to get *all* the entries at once as I'm doing in the code I posted, but you can the results dynamically, bit by bit.